# When calculating the distance between molecules in a solution, is it reasonable to approximate a sphere around each molecule?

Tags: concentration, density

I am attempting to calculate the average distance between molecules in a particular concentration of a solution. My first instinct was to treat the solution as a system of spheres surrounding the solute molecules, the size of which would be dictated by the concentration. Obviously such a calculation of the distance between molecules is primarily dimensional analysis, but is it a realistic treatment of the system, or is there a more appropriate way to arrive at the distance? A spherical treatment, in my mind, has the drawback of not accurately reflecting the distribution of solvent in the solution: a matrix of identically-sized spheres has vacant space, which a solution clearly would not have.

Comment: Which distance do you want to compute? The rdf? The distance of closest approach? An average distance? Why would the solvent matter if small enough? As for packing, you can always expect some empty space, look up "sphere close packing".

Comment: I am attempting to calculate an average distance between molecules.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the dimensions of your container?

Comment: Unless you're thinking about rather high concentrations, that's the way everybody does it. And large molecules which are not in good approximation spherical *and* still soluble are a bit of an oddity.

Comment: Be more specific: What kind of molecules, and what vol% concentration?

Comment: They are fairly small molecules: benzaldehydes; and the molar concentration is intentionally quite dilute: roughly 0.1 M.

Comment: And, sorry for the homework, what is the largest error that you could make by treating the molecules as spherical, and what is the average distance between pointlike molecules at that concentration?

Comment: No worries. I think I didn’t say it clearly enough but the spherical approximation was for the solvent surrounding the molecule. The average distance, using the spherical approximation, is roughly 3 nanometers.

Comment: Ah, OK. You are aware that neighbouring molecules in a condensed phase are in direct contact? I don't understand where you want to go with this.

Comment: I don't see why solvent spheres shall enter in a rough calculation. Treat the molecules as spheres homogenously distributed in a volume.

Comment: My guess is that what you are looking for is an estimate of the distance to the *nearest neighbor* assuming molecules are evenly distributed, right?

Comment: @thornewilder You say you are evaluating the distance between *solvent* molecules, don't you mean *solute* molecules. If you are looking at, say, benzaldehyde at low concentration in, say, ethanol then what you care about is the average distance between *benzaldehyde* molecules not *ethanol* molecules (so the *solute* not the solvent). IS that right?

Comment: Above all, does it exist another model for solving this problem ? Spheres have an advantage. They can be used to make calculations. What else ?

Comment: The nearest neighbour probability of being at distance $r$ is $ w(r)=4\pi r^2n\exp(-4\pi r^3n/3)$ where there are $n$ solute molecules / unit volume which applies when the size of the molecule is small compared to their separation.

Comment: @BuckThorn That is correct. I am attempting to calculate the distance between two solute molecules, and I am assuming that they are evenly distributed in solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribution of molecules in solution is not uniform but has a distribution. The calculation of nearest neighbour distances from one molecule to another has been worked out a long time ago see,  S. Chandrasekhar, Rev. Mod. Phys. 1943, v15, p1.

Let $w(r)$ be the probability that the nearest neighbour occurs between distance  $r$ and $r+dr$. This must be the probability than no molecules exist closer to the victim molecule that one occurs at a distance $r$ and that this molecule exists in the shell $r$ to $r+dr$. Thus,

$$ w(r)=\left(  1-\int_0^r w(r)dr \right)4\pi r^2 n$$

where $n$ is the average number of molecules / unit volume. (1 mol/m<sup>3</sup> $\equiv 10^3N_A/10^{27} = 0.6023 $ molecules / nm$^3$).

This looks hard to solve because $w(r)$ is also inside the integration, so it is necessary to isolate the integral first (by dividing both sides by $4\pi r^2 n$) and then differentiating both sides to find

$$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{w(r)}{4\pi r^2 n}\right)= \frac{d}{dr}\left(1-\int w(r)\right) =-4\pi r^2 n \frac{w(r)}{4\pi r^2 n}$$

and the last step we effectively multiply by 1. The result is

$$ w(r)=4\pi r^2n\exp(-4\pi r^3n/3)$$

The average distance between molecules is

$$\langle r \rangle =\int_0^\infty rw(r)dr =\Gamma (4/3)/(4\pi n/3)^{1/3} =0.55396n^{-1/3}$$

where $n$ is in number of molecules/volume then $n^{-1/3}$ is in units of length.

[image: nearest neighbour]

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to estimate the intermolecular distance is to break up the container into a regular cell array, each cell containing one solute molecule. First invert the concentration to arrive at the volume per molecule. For instance, if you have a 1M concentration, then the molar volume is 1 L/mol. If you divide the molar volume by Avogadro's number you arrive at the volume per molecule. Next each cell, assumed cubic, has sides of length

$$d=\left(\frac{10^{24}}{cN_A}\right)^{1/3}=1.18c^{-1/3}$$

with the distance in nm when the concentration is in mol/L. This is also the distance between the centers of neighboring cells, therefore the estimated average distance between nearest molecules.

The shape of the molecule is not really very relevant unless the concentration is high. Note if solvent molecules are smaller or equal in size to the solute then it's ok to proceed this way. If either (1) the solvent molecules are larger and exclude some of the volume in the container so it becomes unavailable to the solute, or (2) the solute-solute or solvent-solvent interact very strongly, then you need to take the solvent into consideration. The approach applies best to dilute solutions. The approach will of course also fail if the concentration of solute is so high that it would no longer be regarded as the solute. This happens when the intermolecular distance becomes comparable to the size of the molecule.

---

Post-mortem: Porphyrin's result is exact provided the particle distribution is uniform and excluded volume is ignored. My estimate is comparatively pretty bad (off by a factor of ~2). It should not have been surprising. After all the particles on average can only get closer than my estimate. If you have a regular grid, moving one molecule from its position on the grid will bring it closer to another one, making it its nearest-neighbor and reducing the nearest-neighbor distance estimate. Therefore my estimate is in effect *an upper bound*.

Inspired by the better answer, another rough geometric estimate might be made by using the radius of a sphere having the volume per molecule:

$$d=\left(\frac{3\cdot 10^{24}}{4\pi cN_A}\right)^{1/3}=0.735c^{-1/3}$$

Comment: Where does $\ce{10^{24}}$ come from ? What is its unit ? What is C ? In what unit ?

Comment: @Maurice c is the molar concentration, the factor $10^{24}$ converts from L to $nm^3$